# Reading data from SQL Server in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Is there any mechanism with which I can easily read data from SQL Server inside a `get` routine?

Till now I am using my connection string, and sending the query.

`Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlDatabase" 
         connectionString="yourConnectionString"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

ASP.NET MVC code:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
 {
       var connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDatabase "].ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       connection.Open();
 }
```

Is there something easier for reading or writing into SQL Server?

Comment: What do you mean? `Is there something easier for reading or writing into sql server?`

Comment: Is my method right?

Comment: What did you want to do for your code?
You can try to use a class to do encapsulation you sql execute action.  @Dim

Comment: Can you give me an example sir?

Answer (score 0):

There are more options:

1) ADO.NET (Standard open/close connection + data reading) ( https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C )

2) ORMs (Entity framework: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx)

3) Linq to SQL ( https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/an-overview-of-linq-to-sql/ )

I have created one presentation a few years back but its in Czech unfortunately but from slide 29 there are some code examples. ( https://www.slideshare.net/Vtzslavimon/aspnet-mvc-3-and-sql-server-interoperability-overview-cz )